# Mysql. How to replace NULL with certain, predefined value in resultset without COALESCE

Tags: php, mysql

I have such type of query:

```
SELECT table1.field1, table1.field2, table2.field3
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON (...)
```

because of left join i sometimes have table2.field3 NULL

After that in my php script in cycle i redefine it manually

```
...
$row['field3'] = ($row['field3'] === null) ? 'undefined' : $row['field3']; 
...
```

But how can i get this 'undefined' in my result-set?

I ve searched for answer, COALESCE seems to work, but it have some strange logic with many-many arguments.
Seems like it do what i want, but somehow strange..

Im interested if there another simple way to replace my NULL with 'undefined'?

Comment: [`COALESCE` in mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

Comment: have you looked at IFNULL ?

Comment: tim Mickey, nope. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be afraid of COALESCE... its ok.

But, there are other ways:

1. Just use IF & IS NULL

   SELECT table1.field1, table1.field2, IF(table2.field3 IS NULL, 'undefined', table2.field3) AS field3
2. Or simpler, use IFNULL (i believe you will like it)

   SELECT table1.field1, table1.field2, IFNULL(table2.field3, 'undefined') AS field3

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull

Answer (score 1):

You can also use case when,

```
Select 
    case when table1.field1 is null then 
        case when table1.field2 is null then 'undefined'
        else table1.field2 end 
    else table1.field1 end as field1
from tablename
```

you can use nested case when in case you want to check further level conditions.